# jQuery Mask removes the input value after wrong character pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

When you type for example 1a or 22, the input value content disappear.  I want to something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/b4t34zu5/29/  I mean after wrong character contnet not disappear.

```js
$('#x').mask('ZZZDZZ', {    
  translation: {
   'Z': {pattern: /[\d]/, optional: true },
   'D': {pattern: /[\.]/, optional: true },
        
  },
  placeholder: "XXX.XX",
  selectOnFocus: true,
  reverse: true,
  clearIfNotMatch: true
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.9/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="x" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have got it:

```
$('#input').mask('099.00');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you want to accomplish: an input that will allow the user to enter (1) a dollar value from 1-999, (2) an optional cent value from 1-99 with a leading zero for values below 10 and (3) a decimal that appears only in the presence of a cent value.

I think you're needs are a little too complicated for this plugin as you're applying it here and the input is clearing because the regexes are conflicting with one another.  I would recommend that you have two inputs: one for dollars and one for cents, separated by a decimal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I am satisfied with my needs but I have to resolve this specific problem. I can't change this input into two separate inputs because it's about a lot of form fields.